# Cookie not set in request with NodeJS and NextJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, next.js, setcookie

I'm developing a fullstack app with Node + Express backend and NextJS front end (separate servers) and am having trouble requesting the browser to attach the cookie vended down as part of the response header from the node server. Here's the setup:

1. Node server is running on localhost:3000 and NextJs server is running on localhost:3001.
2. I have set up alias in etc/hosts to route someAlias.com to 127.0.0.1.

Using the front end UI (port 3001) I was able to vend the cookie with JsHttp's cookie module with the following code from the backend (port 3000):

```js
import { serialize } from 'cookie';
...
const cookie = serialize(TOKEN_NAME, TOKEN_VAL, {
  httpOnly: true,
  sameSite: 'none',
});
```

I was able to observe the `Set-Cookie` header in the response.

However, in the subsequent requests, I did not see the cookie being attached. I have tried fiddling with the above cookie serialization params with no success:

Here are the arguments I've tried:

- `domain: ['.someAlias.com:3000', '.someAlias.com:3001']`
- `path: '/'`
- `domain: '.someAlias.com'`

I have a feeling it might just be due to front end and back end server ports being different, but all requests have been initiated on the client side going to localhost:3000 (backend port). So not sure what I've possibly done wrong here.

====== UPDATE =======

I've run a couple more experiments, and found out that when I'm accessing a URL directly, NextJs renders the page server-side. When I'm transitioning between pages within the app, the page is rendered client-side where it queries the backend port 3000 directly. Unfortunately in neither scenario did I see any cookie being set...

Answer (score 2):

the cookies must be sent directly from the browser to the server , which is not the case when you use nextJs . because when you access to your app next js will server side render your page and then the request will be sent from nextjs server to your nodejs server so the browser will send the cookies to nextjs server not to your nodejs server .
the solution is to send cookies manually from nextjs server to nodejs .
example with fetchApi and getServerSideProps function:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context){ 
  try{
       const res = await fetch(`your-api-endpoint`, {
          method: 'GET',
          credentials:'include',
          headers: {
             'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
             Cookie: context.req.headers.cookie
          },
    })
    const data = await res.json()
    if(!res.ok){
       throw data 
    }
    }catch(err){
       return console.log(err)
    }

    return {
      props: {
         data
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: httponly cookies will not work here

Answer (score 1):

**SAMESITE NONE**

If you use `SameSite=none` you also need to use `Secure`, meaning SSL must also be used. You are then saying that your 2 servers are from unrelated domains, which is probably not what you want, since browsers will drop cookies aggressively.

**LOCAL PC OPTIONS**

Use these settings initially on your development computer, and ensure that all URLs used in the browser and Ajax calls use http://somealias.com:3000 and http://somealias.com:3001 rather than localhost. Cookies will then stick on a development computer.

- Domain=.somealias.com
- Path=/
- SameSite=strict
- HTTP Only

**DEPLOYED OPTIONS**

When you deploy to a proper environment, also use SSL and set the cookie option `Secure`. Most importantly, the two domains must meet hosting prerequisites of sharing the same base domain, eg:

- https://www.example.com
- https://api.example.com

This ensures that cookies issued are considered first party and in the same site, so that they are not dropped. If preconditions are not met, there is nothing you can do in code to fix the problem.

**SIMILAR RESOURCE**

This [Curity code example](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-handler-spa-example/) uses local development domains and same site cookie settings similar to those I've used above and may be useful to compare against.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work either. Prior to asking the questions i'd already been calling http://somealias.com:3000 and 3001 respectively, i think the problem here is that somealias.com:3000 and 3001 are considered 2 separate domains because their ports are different.

Comment: They are the same domain even if ports are different - the Curity example uses port 80 for www.example.com and port 3000 for api.example.com. Maybe try it with subdomains like that. In production both will need to run on port 443, so you will need to design subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this comment I found on GitHub](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/959#issuecomment-1764907425), if you're setting `sameSite` to `none`, you have to set `secure` to `true`; otherwise, the browser will never save the cookie.

Unfortunately `secure: true` won't work on `localhost` so the workaround would be to check your environment and set `sameSite` to `lax` and `secure` as `false` when working locally.

Your code could look like this:

```js
...
const ENVIRONMENT = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";

const cookie = serialize(TOKEN_NAME, TOKEN_VAL, {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: ENVIRONMENT === "production",
  sameSite: ENVIRONMENT === "production" ? "none" : "lax",
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have to set Cookies manually**

1. install "cookie" in Node js

```npm
npm i cookie
```

```js
import User from "../../models/UserModel.js";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import cookie from "cookie";

export const UserLoginController = async (req, res) => {
try {
 const { email, password } = await req.body;

 //checking user
 const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select("+password");
 if (!user) {
   throw new Error("User not Found");
 }
 console.log(user);

 //checking password
 const isValidPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
 if (!isValidPassword) throw new Error("Invalid password");

 if (user && isValidPassword) {
   const payload = {
     userId: user._id,
   };
   const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET);
   const cookies = cookie.serialize("token", token);
   return res.status(200).json({ message: "Login successful", cookies });
 }
} catch (error) {
 return res.status(401).json(error.message);
}
};
```

1. Now Insatll react-cookies in Next js

```npm
npm i react-cookie
```

You can read more about [react-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie)

```js
const LoginSubmitHandler = async (data: any) => {
    try {
      console.log(data);
      const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/users/login", data);
      const cookies = res.data.cookies.split("=")[1];
      console.log(cookies);
      setCookies("token", cookies);

      toast.success(res.data.message);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error);
      toast.error(error.response.data);
    }
  };
```

**In this way you can set cookies manually**

Answer (score -1):

You should set serialized cookie with [res.set](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set) Express method.

Alternatively, you can use [res.cookie](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie) method without additional `cookie` package like this:

```js
res.cookie(TOKEN_NAME, TOKEN_VAL, {
  httpOnly: true,
  sameSite: 'none',
});
```

Note, you shouldn't worry about different ports on the same domain, since cookies are not isolated by port but domain only. No matter what port you use, cookies should be visible.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to note I've tried that as well, didn't work :(

Comment: @ddolce How do you make requests from Next.js application to your Node.js server?